# Como usar retornar valores usando .map() no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter, map

eu estou tentando fazer um metodo `.map()`, porém não estou conseguindo. Meu ultimo código foi esse:

```js
var double = x => x * 2;

function filtro(funcao, numeros) {
 let arr = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
   arr.push(numeros[i](funcao));
   }
   return arr;
}
    


console.log(filtro(double, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]));
```

Teria que retornar: 2,4,6,4,10.. etc..

Alguem pode me ajudar ?

Comment: O código está perdendo a endentação, já editei duas vezes.

Comment: @wmsouza Fala mano, boa noite.

É não, ali ele usa o map do javascript, no meu código no caso, eu estou criando o map, entendeu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do jeito que o código está, basta você chamar o método passando como parâmetro `numeros[i]` veja que `i` é o índice de cada elemento.

```js
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10];
var i = 4; // Índice

// Saida => 5
console.log(numeros[i]);

i = 2; // Índice

// Saida => 3
console.log(numeros[i]);


i = 6; // Índice

// Saida => 7
console.log(numeros[i]);
```

#### Veja funcionando

```js
var double = (x) => x * 2;

function filtro(funcao, numeros) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
    arr.push(funcao(numeros[i]));
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log( filtro(double, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]) );
```

Comment: Caraca cara, muito obrigado.

Eu tinha feito exatamente esse código, o que me passou despercebido foi os parametros, em vez de tá (funcao, numeros), tava (numeros, funcao).